# Global min-max optimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, global-optimization

When is

\begin{equation}
\min_X \max_Y f(X,Y)
\end{equation}

globally solvable? I.e., when can we find global solution for the optimization problem?

I am not looking for reformulations. Is it only when $f$ is concave in $Y$ and convex in $X$?

Answer (score 1):

There are primarily two things -

1. convexity/concavity of domain
2. convexity/concavity of objective function

A convex domain enables us to make strong comments regarding the global maxima and minima.

The objective function will have a maximum iff it is concave in the domain and min iff it is convex. This statement can be made if we have been given that the domain in convex.

Comment: Considering that we have min over max how does this apply?

Comment: I am not very clear about the problem statement(what does min over max mean)  but if X is the domain for maximization part of the problem and Y for the minimization then yes the conditions you mention are necessary.

Comment: Also these arguments are made for an open set.

Comment: I did not receive any response after setting the bounty, so I think no one gets bounty from my side.